# CakePhp model binding custom field

Tags: php, database, cakephp, binding, cakephp-model

Lets say I have the following DB [image]

```
[Objects] 
 1
 2

[Settings] 
 x
 y
 a
 b
 c

[ObjectSettings]
 1, x
 1, y
 2, a
 2, b
 2, c
```

so object 1 has (x,y) and 2 has (a,b,c)

now in the UI, the combination of the settings like (x,y) and (a,b,c) has specific names,

```
(x,y) = SettingA
(a,b,c) = SettingB
```

The UI should be agnostic of the details and only bind to the two fields on the model and show as it is on the UI.

something like

```
class Object extends Model {
    public $fields = array(
     .
     .
     .
     'SettingA' =>....,
     'SettingB' =>...

     )
    }
```

So in my CakePhp [Object] Model I want to have 2 fields/virtualFields/whatever called SettingA and SettingB, each would be true/false. I would call a service to transform and persist the ObjectSettings correctly on the DB.

1. **Normal fields** : The problem with this is that only by looking at the fields array, it looks like the fields are there in the database as they are grouped together with other regular fields. The actual binding of those fields will happen in the overrides of beforeSave and afterFind callbacks.
2. **Virtual Fields** : although it supports custom sql but It does not support saving.

What is the best Cakephp way of mapping those fields to the model, so that i could both save and read doing the transformations necessary. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to name a _set_ (that is a specific combination) of settings?

Comment: my main issue is not the combination sets. Assume that logic could be in the sql query. My issue is how would I map that query to a field in the cake php model and retrieve/save that using Cake only.

Comment: i want to override the save/retrieve logic for my custom field.

Comment: What is the query that you want to map to the field?